# Import only planet_osm_polygon osm2pgsql

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, geofabrik

My purpose its to only use queries with the ST_Contains function, so for me to have only the `planet_osm_polygon` its enough i think. How can i tune the osm2pgsl cli command or the style file to import only this kind of polygon data without POIs, roads, etc...?
I dont know what tables are strictly necessary or which ones can be avoided.

[image]